# Facebook upload fan page in PHP not working anymore

Tags: php, facebook-page, photo-upload

I'm using the following code to upload photos to Facebook fan page **as the page** (not as a user):

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api ( '/'.$fanpageid.'/photos' , 'POST' , array(  
 'source' => '@' . $filename,
 'message' => $message,
 'link'=>$link,
 'access_token'=>$accesstoken
));
```

This code was working until June 11th, 12 AM. Did Facebook change the way it works?

I have the fan page access token, and everything was working fine. How do I make it work?

Comment: It might be worth adding what exactly happens when you try it. Do you get errors? Elaborate on *what* doesn't work.

Comment: found the solution myself, an alternative way is working
instead of

'source' => '@' . $filename,

using
'url' => $fullpathfilename,

is working, weird that facebook doesnt document those important changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution myself, an alternative way is working instead of

```
'source' => '@' . $filename,
```

using

```
'url' => $fullpathfilename,
```

is working, weird that facebook doesnt document those important changes.

Comment: That's not an "important change", it's always worked that way. The first method is a way of uploading directly from your filesystem. The second method gives Facebook a URL to pull the image from. The first still works fine if you're doing it correctly - check that `$filename` is a valid path to the file.

Comment: that's the thing source did work until a couple of hours ago.
$filename is the correct one
changing

    $facebook->api ( '/'.$fanpageid.'/photos' , 'POST' , array(

to 

$facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(

still works with source, but of course posting to my own timeline

it's only the upload to fanpage that doesn't work with source anymore